# Why doesn't my dataset fill?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am adding a select statement from a mySQL database to a dataset but it does not fill the dataset.
Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code?

```
string connString = "server = bla; user id = bla;  Password = bla;  database = bla;";
string query = "Select * From oc_product;";
MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connString);
MySqlCommand mysqlcmd = new MySqlCommand(query, conn);
conn.Open();
MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(mysqlcmd);

da.Fill(dsProducts);

conn.Close();
```

Comment: You get any exception or error message? Are you sure your `mysqlcmd` returns data? Are you sure you can open your connection? Did you debug your code line by line? What is `dsProducts`? We need more details about your problem. And you should use _using statement_ to dispose your database connections as well.

Comment: can you also show us dsProducts?

Comment: No errors are given when i go over it line by line, but when i try use the dsProducts later its empty. im using it later to count the rows in it and it says it cant find table[0]. i go look at its properties and it says the count of tables is 0, thats where i hit my error. How do i check if my mysqlcmd returns something?

Comment: @TaW dsProducts is an empty dataset. earlier in the code i just declare it as an empty dataset.

Comment: @AndreaVisnenzaAndy is you connection string valid? You can view example strings here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: my problem was my logic... sigh. thanx for the help anyway guys.